# How to join two tables by attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

Country table

```
Country region
AU       ANZ
NZ       ANZ
```

Rules table

```
Attr_1    Attr_2    Attr_3    Country 
 z         1          s         AU
 b         3          a         AU
 c         9          l         NZ
 m         -          i         DE
```

Now i want to write a single query which give me all rows where country belong to region ANZ. In the above case for example 3 rows except row 4 where country is DE and dont belong to region ANZ. Is this possible using single query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the tables and then filter by country table:

```
SELECT Rules.* 
FROM Rules
    INNER JOIN Country ON Rules.Country = Country.Country
WHERE Country.Region = 'ANZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Attr_1, Attr_2, Attr_3, Country
FROM Country
INNER JOIN Rules
ON Country.Country=Rules.Country
WHERE Country.region='ANZ'
```

Comment: Why are you adding in DISTINCT?

Comment: DISTINCT was given as a precaution in case the Country table was a snippet of the original table; for example if the Country table had also two other columns valid_from and valid_to and two rows with AU and ANZ but with different valid_from, valid_to then duplicate tuples {Attr_1, Attr_2, Attr_3, Country} would be returned from the join execution.

Comment: I can't upvote your (correct) answer when it goes beyond the question, answering something that is not being asked for. I hope that makes sense.